# Google My Activity API?

Tags: google-chrome, google-developers-console, google-developer-tools

At [myactivity.google.com](https://myactivity.google.com/), you can view all your Google activity. It's super rich data , and I'd love to be able to access my own programatically.

Does anyone know if there is a **public API** to access this data, or if there is one in the works?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a kind of a workaround, you can go to https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout, request "My Activity" events, let Google store them on your Google Drive (zipped or gzipped) and access the archive via Google Drive API.

Comment: I think this is the closest way to achieve this